# Why do the layout positions change in preview when I simply add a new screen size to the preview screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a 4 inch screen displayed in Assistant Editor Preview while I'm adding constraints to the view controller in Storyboard. Once I get everything situated in the correct position with the constraints and the layout looks good on the 4 inch screen, I then add another screen size to the preview window. For some reason, just by adding another screen size to the Preview window causes the layout preview on my perfectly good 4 inch screen to slightly be changed. Is this odd behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your project have any funny characters in its name, such as a question mark? That can cause the Preview feature to behave oddly (believe it or not)...

Comment: I checked, but I don't see any that are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but instead with the 4.7 inch screen size. I found that using 2 things helped me keep the layout and constraints consistent across all screen sizes.

First, keep your storyboard default layout to universal (square) so the constraints aren't applied to one screen size only.

Second, when setting your constraints, use the "Reset to suggested constraints" button located on the third constraints tab.

I have yet to experience layout issues using this method. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Zach. When you say "keep your storyboard default layout to universal (square)", is that the same as selecting "Inferred" size for the storyboard? Also, when you use "Reset to suggested constraints" have you experienced any problems when you have to resize the cell based on the amount text a label contains within a cell? Or, are you still able to grow the cell dynamically?

Comment: Correct, the storyboard window size should be left "inferred". As far as cell resizing, i have not had a chance to test that. So far my text fields have been a set size.

Comment: Have you been able to verify the layout works on all screen sizes with no dead space?

Comment: I have with the app I am currently working on. I have used suggested constraints with inferred layout in the story board, no dead space on the devices i have test it on (iPhone 6, 6+, 5S, 5)

Comment: I may give that a try and see how it works with my layout. Thanks for the reply, Zach.

Comment: No problem! If you come across anymore issues post a comment and i will test your code and attempt to solve the problem. Good luck!